# Way to control editor for individual cell in Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to figure out how to control an individual cell's editor (not column, a particular cell) in Telerik's RadGrid control.

For example, I need the following layout:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Name Column |Col 1              | Col 2             | Col 3             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Some Name    | <drop down>      | <drop down>       | <drop down>       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Another Name | <drop down>      | <drop down>       |<drop down>        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check These | <checkbox>       | <checkbox>        | <checkbox>        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|<submit button>                                                         |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Having it do the drop down lists and also putting in the submit button at the bottom is no problem.  However, I can't figure out how to set the editor for the checkbox cells to be checkboxes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Telerik grid the editors are set per column basis as this is normal, Chris - the column values are of the same type and it is not logical to have dropdown editor and boolean/checkbox editor within the same column. The only possible solution might be to use single [global item template](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/cardview/defaultcs.aspx) (one row) or single template column with all the editors inside it. Not sure how this works in your case though.

Comment: Thanks for answering; I ended up just coding my own grid to support this.  Took about 4 hours which was faster than trying to push RadGrid into doing something it obviously wasn't designed to do.

Comment: And just to clarify, we had other requirements.  Such as inline editing, columns created at runtime (unknown #), and needed not just checkboxes, but also 2 rows of regular textboxes in addition to the drop down lists.  The first 2 RadGrid was a breeze to get going.  The others kind of pushed it into unknown territory.